# Visual Studio 2015 (C#) doesn't find and cannot install Android SDK

Tags: android, visual-studio, sdk, installation, xamarin-studio

I've just reinstalled Visual Studio Community 2015 (Win10). It was installed previously but then had similar problems with compiling for Android. First time I opened it, the Tools/Android menu was available, but when I chose "*Android SDK Manager*" everything but "*Manage Virtual Devices*" grayed out. I (try to) use c# with Xamarin for mobile devices. The Xamarin part I did not re-install, so VS found and reuses the old Xamarin installation.

When I look at "*Properties*" of the Droid part of a "*Solution*", I cannot choose any API Level to compile for, but the Minimum Android to target has a list available. "*Build*" results in an error list beginning with "*The XamlCTask task could not be instantiated from C:*\"... I installed Android Studio with Android SDK and that seems to work fine.

Is it in any way possible to make Visual Studio 2015 understand that Android SDK is installed on the computer?

Comment: Hi LocalFluff, you can check the Nuget Package Manager for Visual studio 2015 already updated to the latest version (3.4.4.1321), then right click the solution name, choose ‘Manage Nuget Packages for Solution…’ and click the ‘Updates’/’Consolidate’ tab and if there have any updates about Xamarin items, you can check them to install for all projects under this solution, then clean up the solution and rebuild it again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - can you look under Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android and check the path of the Android SDK, NDK, and the JDK?

If you have these installed, you may need to point VS to their correct locations.

Let me know if that works, I'm curious what happened in the update to do this.

Comment: I did that. All those three file paths have green light and their folders do exist. It failed as it failed before I re-installed it. With the same incomprehensible error message about the XamlCTask task not being able to instantiate itself. This when I just try to build from selecting New Solution / Visual C# / Blank app Xamarin Forms Portable. What can one do about VS not understanding that Android SDK is live and well in the folders I have given it the path to? Is this software intentionally meant to be unusable?

Comment: Now the inte-lligent Visual Studio oracle is telling me that it cannot find "android.jar for API Level 23". But API 23 is fully installed and works very well for Android studio. Is it possible to let Visual studio know about that SDK actually is installed in the folder I've told it that it is installed in? VS is just another Microsoft Failware. Page 1 in the manual is just a lie, the premises are wrong. Worse than that, they are false, they are fraudulent. One is just stupid to be fooled to try to use this spam shit.

Comment: No, the software is not meant to be unusable, and while I understand your frustration I would also like to help you with your problem, so let's focus on getting this working. Is Android Studio pointed to the same location of the Android SDK as Xamarin Studio?

Comment: misskallisto and every one else here. I've re-installed everything again (VS, Xamarin, SDK whatever) and now it works. I assume that it will crash again when VS forces an update next week. But it only takes a better part of a day to re-install everything from scratch again so that VS can find the SDK files. I'm sorry that my frustration spills over to an attitude here, but VS is so very buggy that it is easier to develop for IOS and Android separately than trying to use C# Xamarin for both at a time. Nice idea, but it doesn't work. And with MS heading it now I presume that it will never work.

Comment: I have no idea whatsoever why Visual Studio again and again makes itself totally useless. I just want to develop software, not administrating other's buggy software.

Comment: I'm glad it worked with a re-install, but would like to know why the SDKs weren't found. VS 2017 fixes many of these issues with a new and better installer :).

Comment: misskallisto Thank you, I'm happy too, for the moment. But why would anyone be interested in WHY it failed? Next time it will fail for another reason anyway. Understanding a bug isn't knowledge, it is a unique event from which nothing can be learned. And oh yeah, I'm sure, finally VS 2017 will end bugs! No it will be even worse. More updates and every update requires a full re-installation.It will keep getting much worse. Luckily, I can at least use Android Studio. And Xamarin Studio for Mac seems to be reliable too. Visual studio is obviously beyond the competence of Microsoft.

Comment: Glad you like VS for Mac, my team built that. It's based off of Xamarin Studio, which is even better since VS for Mac is still in preview.